# Re-hide dynamic div content when a new selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

While the code below works great to dynamically switch my div content, the problem now is that the javascript code does not hide the user's previous selection. Any ideas on how to amend the code to dynamically switch div content and hide the users previous selection that was made?

Here is the HTML and Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
window.onload = function() {    
    $("li").click(function(){            
          var $li = $(this);              
          var selector = $li.data("show");   // => "#item1"                       
          $(selector).removeClass("hidden"); //but show matching item              
    });    
}
</script>    

<style type="text/css">    
#container {
    bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
}
#list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#list li {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    background: grey;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(192,192,192);    
}
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #ff99CC;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: rgb(192,192,192);
    height: 100%;
}
.hidden{ display:none; }
</style>

</head>    
<body>    
    <div id="container">        
        <div id="menu">         
            <ul id="list">
               <li data-show="#item1">Coffee</li>
               <li data-show="#item2">Tea</li>
               <li data-show="#item3">Ice Cream</li>
            </ul>           
        </div>          
        <div id="content">          
        <div id="item1" class="hidden item">Something about coffee...</div>         
        <div id="item2" class="hidden item">Things about tea...</div>           
        <div id="item3" class="hidden item">Things about ice cream...</div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to remove the class hidden but it's not removing ?

Comment: Just keep a reference to the currently selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this: https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/2xr1zy2b/

```
$("li").click(function(){ 
          var $li = $(this);
          var selector = $li.data("show");   // => "#item1"
          $('.item').addClass('hidden');
          $(selector).removeClass("hidden"); //but show matching item
});
```

also you can validate using filter for `id` value https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/2xr1zy2b/1/

```
$("li").click(function(){ 
    var $li = $(this);
    var selector = $li.data("show");   // => "#item1"
    $(selector).removeClass("hidden"); //but show matching item
    $('.item').filter(function(){ 
        return selector.indexOf($(this).attr('id')) > -1 ? false : true;
     }).addClass('hidden');
});
```